# minor change needed to javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I have a requirement for obtaining the content of an iframe within a web page. I found the following code which does this correctly---

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Function can also be loaded from an external file -->
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName) // the function has one parameter: the iframe's ID.
{                                         // I did it this way, so you can call it for multiple iframes.

    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName); // Creating an object of the iframe
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML; // Getting it's content into a variable

// Basically now, in the variable 'content' you have the content of your iframe,
// and can do anything you want with it.
alert('content: ' + content);    // here it is


// You can even choose to change it afterwards
content = 'The inside of my frame has now changed'; // create a new content
myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = content; // and set it
}

</script>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe> <!-- Instantiating the iframe -->
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="getContentFromIframe('iframe1')">Get the content</a> <!-- Calling the function -->

</body>

</html>
```

Now I plan to use the above code in a Google Chrome extension- basically when I click on the button for the extension then javascript code will be injected into the web page, and here I need to obtain the content of iframe named "iframe1".

I understand that in function 'getContentFromIframe' the value of iframe's id is passed as input parameter. So I changed the code to following, hoping to obtain the content of iframe--

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframe1'); // Creating an object of the iframe
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML; // Getting it's content into a variable

// Basically now, in the variable 'content' you have the content of your iframe,
// and can do anything you want with it.
alert('content: ' + content);    // here it is
```

However I am not getting any value of iframe content. What I am doing wrong here? I dont know much javascript, so I suspect that my syntax is wrong somewhere?

Given below is the content of my manifest.json---

```
{
  "name": "Link Submitter",
   "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "bg.html",
  "description": "Link Submitter by SEO Power Toys",
   "browser_action": {
      "name": "Send Data",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "Send data to Link Submitter"      // optional; shown in tooltip
  },  
  "permissions": [ "tabs",
       "bookmarks",
           "http://*/*",
           "https://*/*",
            "unlimitedStorage"
     ]

}
```

Also given below is the error message I am getting in Javascript console, when I try to run the Google Chrome extension-

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

Comment: You must be trying to violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: What is in your "manifest.json"? You probably don't have the right permissions.

Comment: Also, as @Shref notes, this is a same-origin violation. There are some ways to get around it... but it's not really good security-wise.

Comment: i am running chrome with appropriate security flags disabled, so as to disable same origin policy- when I directly opened the HTML web page, I was able to access the content of iframe successfully. however when i made changes as described in my question, its not working...

Comment: I copy-pasted your code directly to a local file, opened it in Safari and it worked just as the code states.

Comment: update- i checked the javascript console, when i am running the google chrome extension, this is the error that i am getting -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined. Can someone tell me how to resolve this? Thanks...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Chrome console?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access or manipulate the contents of `<iframe>` elements that contain content from a domain different from your own. There are some ways of communicating between frames, but they require the content from both domains to be prepared to do that; you can't just expect any random page to work with those (fairly new) APIs.

Now, from an **extension**, of course, the rules are different.  If you're playing around with the code on a regular web page, however, it just won't work.

*edit* — [Here](http://gutfullofbeer.net/iframe-question/iframe.html) is a test case for your code.  It seems to work just fine.

Comment: please refer to my comments above

Comment: Well let me try a similar experiment ... I presume you're talking about the "--allow-file-access-from-files" switch.

Comment: Hi please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy...

Comment: i understand that directly injected into an html page as pure javascript, the code is working.. what i fail to understand is why the same code gives an error message when that code is injected into a page from google chrome extension as a content script...

Comment: Ah, OK - I apologize for not recognizing the nature of your particular scenario.  My Chrome extension experience is extremely limited and I've never tried what you're doing.